# Late 80s or early 90s book includes genetically engineered executioner with gills

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, post-apocalyptic, genetic-engineering

A male main character was genetically engineered, had gills in his throat, and was an executioner in a post-apocalyptic world. He was able to move long distances instantly through something called the bine toad.

Comment: Are you sure about the *bine toad*? That's such an unusual term I'm sure I would remember having read it, but I don't remember anything like that and Googling fails to find anything related.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a long shot, but could the book be [The Marked Man](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?561793) by Charles Ingrid (aka Rhondi A. Vilott Salsitz).

It's set in a world where technology used for genetic engineering has gone wrong and caused a plague that wiped out most humans and left the remainder genetic freaks. The protagonist is Thomas Blade, who does have gills and is an executioner.

Blade can travel long distances on the *Ghost Road*, so this vaguely matches your description, but there is no mention of a *bine toad*.

The book was published in 1989 so it's in your date range.

Comment: I meant bone road.  Auto correct band fat fingers got me i was using my phone.  Mr Rennie that is the book thnks for evryones help.

Comment: @DavidMyers: hmm, there is no *bone road* in this book though Blade does use finger bones to open the *ghost road*. Anyhow, if this is the book please will you click the tick symbol on the left to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: You are correct mr. Rennie.  You did answer my question. The book was marked man. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering this, I've been looking for this book on and off for a few years.

My local library has it, so now I can go read it!